# Running entire Python script in one line

Tags: python, exec, traceback

I have developed a Python script to reference another Python file with functions to compute KPIs. Then, using the main file, the KPIs are cleaned and ordered and finally outputted to a word doc. In the process I am also referring an Excel file to provide further user-desired inputs.

Now I want to be able to just use one line to run the entire file. I have tried and have in the past successfully used:

```
exec(open("binary2.py").read())
```

However, with this file, I am running into a certain error which I am not facing when I simply run binary1.py on its own. As in, error happens only using the exec command.

> > AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> > ----> 1 exec(open("binary2.py").read())
>
> in
>
> ~\Desktop\Model_Validation\Playbook XLS and Jupyter
> Notebook\BinaryKPI_PythonFunctionsV3.py in data_vars(df1, target)
> 662     stack = traceback.extract_stack()
> 663     filename, lineno, function_name, code = stack[-2]
> --> 664     vars_name = re.compile(r'((.*?)).*$').search(code).groups()[0]
> 665     final = (re.findall(r"[\w']+", vars_name))[-1]
> 666
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

There is a function which I am calling in the binary2 file which calls for the Traceback. It seems this Traceback is not getting carried over while using exec command.

I also tried:

```
source = open("binary2.py").read()
code2 = compile(source, filename, 'exec')
exec(code2)
```

but to no benefit.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,
Ansh

Edit: The code generating an error while running the `exec` command runs fine while running the py file directly:

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: The problem is with the error itself, it doesn't have to do with the way that you run the file

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean when you say 'the problem is with the error itself" - does this mean the stack is by definition not to be carried over?

Comment: `re.compile(r'((.?)).$').search(code)` is returning `None` looks like. But this code runs fine if you run the .py directly?

Comment: Yes - the code runs fine while running the file directly - edited the OP with a screenshot